# preg_replace_callback() - Callback inside current object instance

Tags: php

Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'info', to be a valid callback in [...]

```
public function getDisplay(){
    $info = array_merge($this->info,array());

    return  preg_replace_callback('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', 'info', $this->display);
}
```

In a public function from "MyClass", stopped working when I moved from another class to this one. Which was:

```
public function getEdit( $type){
    $all_info = $this->info;

    return preg_replace_callback('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', 'all_info', $edit_contents);
}
```

Both are cleaned up, and now I can't retest with previous class because it's already long gone.

I'm sure using variables is **not** allowed, but it was working, so I'm clueless.

When I do this, as suggested in some stackoverflow thread, but obviously it's **not** made to be used within objects:

```
public function getDisplay(){
    $display_info = $this->info;

    function display_info($matches) {
        global $display_info;
        return $display_info[$matches[1]];
    }

    return  preg_replace_callback('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', 'display_info', $this->display);
}
```

So I need some love and guidance cuz php is driving me crazy this week...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *correct* way to do this would be with a closure:

```
public function getDisplay() {

    // While $this support in closures has been recently added (>=5.4.0), it's
    // not yet widely available, so we'll get another reference to the current
    // instance into $that first:
    $that = $this;

    // Now we'll write that preg... line of which you speak, with a closure:
    return  preg_replace_callback('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', function($matches) use($that) {
        return $that->info[$matches[1]];
    }, $this->display);

}
```

Comment: That is soo bootyfull!! Way too nice to not be used! But my version is 5.3.x Damn that Wamp!

Comment: 5.3 is fine for the above code, it's just if you are 5.2 or less that closures don't work.

Comment: The 5.4 constraint is just for using the magic variable `$this` within a closure, which is why I created `$that`. The one issue with this is that the property `info` will need to be `public`.

Comment: This would be nice: 
 `function($matches) use($that) {
 return $that->getInfo()[$matches[1]]`. But if I remember correctly PHP disallows that...

Comment: @localhost That syntax is known as array dereferencing and it [works as of 5.4](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0). No dice if you're stuck with 5.3 though.

Comment: Although you could make your `getInfo()` method accept an argument, and have it return that specific key if the argument is passed and the whole of `info` if it isn't. Then you can just pass `$matches[1]` into `getInfo()`

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using anonymous functions or more complex methods, you can just use one of methods supported for passing callbacks ([see the documentation on callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

To pass "info" method of current object as a callback, just do the following:

```
array($this, 'info')
```

and pass it wherever you want to use "info" method as a callback within one of the objects other methods.

Comment: +1 IMO this is the correct way to do it, in other functions which have callbacks as well.  Closures seem a bit...cramped, frantic.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it:

```
public function getDisplay(){
    return  preg_replace_callback('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', array(get_class($this), '_preg_replace_callback'), $this->display);
}

private function _preg_replace_callback($matches){
    return $this->info[$matches[1]];
}
```

I did try this approach before, but didn't use the `get_class()` function to wrap `$this`. Oh bother...

Comment: you shouldn't need get_class().  `array($this, '_preg_replace_callback')` is ok. actually, i don't think your posted solution can work.

Comment: well it did work, and wasn't working without get_class()...It's PHP, go figure...