# Convert deprecated function preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, callback

I have the following piece of code: http://pastebin.com/VaZkRxSu. And I am trying to update the functions `preg_replace` with `preg_replace_callback`. I don't understand what would be the `callback` in my case.
 `A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement string. This is the callback signature:
string handler ( array $matches )` - This is what it says on php.net.
Issue is located on following lines:

Line 160

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("!{$ldq}\*.*?\*{$rdq}!se","",$file_contents);
```

In this case preg_replace replacement is an empty field `""`. I have tried just changing the preg_replace to preg_replace_callback, but I get error: `(2) preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback`.

Line 163

```
$file_contents = preg_replace('%(<\?(?!php|=|$))%i', '<?php echo \'\\1\'?>'."\n", $file_contents);
```

Line 168

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("!{$ldq}\s*literal\s*{$rdq}(.*?){$ldq}\s*/literal\s*{$rdq}!s", stripslashes($ldq . "literal" . $rdq), $file_contents);
```

Line 173

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("!{$ldq}\s*php\s*{$rdq}(.*?){$ldq}\s*/php\s*{$rdq}!s", stripslashes($ldq . "php" . $rdq), $file_contents);
```

Line 196

```
$text[$i+1] = preg_replace('~^(\r\n|\r|\n)~', '', $text[$i+1]);
```

Line 208

```
$compiled_text = preg_replace('!\?>\n?<\?php!', '', $compiled_text);
```

I also tried adding as the callback a function($m) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164563/preg-replace-callback-calback-inside-current-object-instance)

Please help me on this, I am a noob and doing my best on learning php.

Comment: @mario I checked that question too, but the second argument I don't think is dynamic or null like in my case.

Comment: `preg_replace` itself isn't deprecated. It's only the `/e` eval modifier. Hence does not apply to your empty-replacement plain `preg_replace` calls.

Comment: @mario, I see so I can use `preg_replace` without the e modifier, and how to do that?

Comment: You're already doing so in five out of six of your examples.

Comment: @mario hmm, I am really trying to figure it out. But can't see which is the modifier.

Comment: They are `!se` (probably needlessly including the eval modifier) in your first example, and `%i` in the second, `!i` in the third and fourth example. The other calls do not contain any letter (=modifier) after the regex delimiter.

Comment: I see now, deleted `se` and it;s working perfectly. Thank you Mario.